# how do i get all already selected checkbox value in edit page in mvc using jquery

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, checkbox

i have an edit page in which user have to select the  checkbox and then it selected values will be submitted to the database which is working but there is one problem i have to catch all the selected values of checkbox which was selected at the creation time. how do i get that the already selected checkbox value on edit page.
here is my code for submitting.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#btn-gn').click(function () {
        var list = [];
        $('#MySelection input:checked').each(function () {
            list.push(this.name);
        });
        // now names contains all of the names of checked checkboxes
        // do something with it for excamle post with ajax
        $.ajax({
            url: '@Url.Action("RoleEdit","Role")',
            type: 'POST',
            data: { Parameters: list},
            success: function (result) {
                alert("success");
            },
            error: function (result) {
                alert("error!");
            }
        });   //end ajax
    });
});



 <div id="MySelection">
        @for (int i = 0; i < Model.PermissionsList.Count; i++)
            {
        <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-1 col-sm-1">

           <input type="checkbox" name="tags" class="no-margin"
            id="=ids" value="@Model.PermissionsList[i].PermissionId" >

       </div>
        <div class="col-md-11 col-sm-11">
              @Model.PermissionsList[i].PermissionName

       </div>
        </div>
            }
        </div>
```

here is my controller :

```
[HttpGet]
        public ActionResult RoleEdit(int id,ViewModelRole viewModelRole)
        {

             viewModelRole.Role = roleService.GetRole(id);
             viewModelRole.PermissionsList = preFlightDbContext.Permissions.ToList();
            return View(viewModelRole);
        }

        [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult RoleEdit(ViewModelRole viewModelRoleForAdd, string[] tags)
        {
            string addPer = delemetedString(tags, ',');
            try
            {
                if (ModelState.IsValid)
                {

                   viewModelRoleForAdd.Role= roleService.UpdateRole(role);
                    roleService.SaveRole();
                    return RedirectToAction("RoleLists");
                }
            }
            catch (DataException)
            {
                ModelState.AddModelError("", "Unable to save changes. Try again, " +
                  "and if the problem persists see your system administrator.");
            }
            return View(viewModelRoleForAdd);
        }



private string delemetedString(string[] input, char delemeter)
        {
            string output = String.Empty;
            for (int i = 0; i < input.Length; i++)
            {
                if (i == input.Length - 1)
                    output += input[i];
                else
                    output += input[i] + delemeter;
            }
            return output;
        }
```

Comment: Can you add your controller class. The code looks right so far

Comment: ok i am updating my code

Comment: you can add a checkchange event on the checkboxes, and keep a list of names which have been changed.

Comment: Do you want the names of the checkboxes? or the values?

Comment: @ Stephen Muecke i want the Check box  appeared in edit page with checked checkboxes

Comment: Your parameter is named `tags` but your posting back to `Parameters` (they should match) - but the array will contain only `["tag", "tag", ...]` because your getting the name, not the value of the checkbox. You will also need to use `traditional: true` in the ajax

Comment: sir my above code is for posting the selected checkbox value using comma seprated string to the controller. what i am asking is to how to get all the selected checkbox value that are already exists and here in edit page user can select or deselect the existing checked values. can you please help me on this.

Comment: @ Stephen Muecke sir your suggestions are always precious and very effective thankyou

Comment: @user3548608, I'm not sure what your trying to do. Did my answer to one of your previous questions [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27123817/getting-multiple-checkboxes-selection-and-seprated-with-comma) not help. It appears to be very similar.

Comment: no sir that was very helpful.

Comment: @ Stephen Muecke sir need some help as per your suggestion checkboxes are selecting but what i have tried is not properly working i am getting all my checkboxes selected. cant able to understand where i am doing wrong.

Comment: @StackOverflow, I have shown you how to do this (and I assure you it works). Your question also seems to be related to [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27385208/how-to-uncheck-the-checked-checkbox-and-based-on-that-remove-that-id-value-from). Sorry to be harsh but nothing in this code makes any sense and its unclear what your trying to achieve.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest something like this:

```
public class PermissionsListItem()
{
   public int Id {get; set;}
   public string Name {get; set;}
   public bool isChecked {get; set;}
}
```

Now the controller action methods:

```
public ViewResult Index()
{
   ...code to build up a List<PermisionListItem>()

   return View(List<PermissionListItem> model goes here);
}

[POST]
public ActionResult Edit(List<PermissionListItem> items)
{
   iterate through your model to see what is checked.
}
```

The Razor View

```
@model IEnumerable<PermissionListItem>

<div id="MySelection">
@using(Html.BeginForm())
{  
    @for (var item in model)
    {
        <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-1 col-sm-1">
            @Html.CheckBoxFor(x => @item.IsSelected, new { name="tags", @class="no-margin"})

       </div>
       <div class="col-md-11 col-sm-11">
           @item.Name
       </div>
   </div>
   }
</div>
}
```

Comment: can you please give the complete example

Comment: what i trying is getting some error
viewModelRole.Permiss = preFlightDbContext.Permissions
                .Select(p => new List<PermissionViewModel>()
                {
                    Id = p.PermissionId,
                    Name = p.PermissionName
                });